# realtime replication oracle 10g to kafka by goldengate

Tags: apache-kafka, oracle10g, oracle-golden-gate

We have an old system running on oracle 10g, now we need to analyze its data, we prepare to replication the data to kafka in realtime, I learned goldengate through , but I don't know how to implement it.

ps: Can't upgrade oracle 10g and don't known the version limit of goldengate

Answer (score 0):

You can use GoldenGate 11 (unsupported now) to extract the data from the source database (Extract process). And GoldenGate for Kafka adapter for the Replicat process to pass the data.

Every GoldenGate binaries are prepared to read a stream changes in a certain Oracle database version. Look at the documentation for details. Old versions (unsupported) of Oracle database are also not supported.

You can also try to use some open source solutions like [OpenLogReplicator](https://github.com/bersler/OpenLogReplicator), but it does not support Oracle 10g version at this moment.